# How do I preserve the selected checkbox in primeNG datatable

Tags: angular, primeng

This is my primeNG datatable html definition:

```
<p-dataTable
  #datatable
  [value]="datasource"
  [(selection)]="data"
  [totalRecords]="totalRecords"
  selectionMode="multiple"
  resizableColumns="true"
  [pageLinks]="10"
  [rows]="10"
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100]"
  [paginator]="true"
  [responsive]="true"
  [lazy]="true"
  (onLazyLoad)="setDatasource($event)"
  (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
  (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)"
>
  <p-column selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of dt.colDefs" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.headerName" [sortable]="true">
    <template *ngIf="col.template" let-data="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
      <div [innerHTML]="col.template(data) | sanitizeHtml" (click)="col.funcCallback(data)"></div>
    </template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I have used many features in one table such as: lazy loading, pagination, selection, etc.

I tried to select a checkbox, then moved to next page.
When I moved back to previous page, the checkbox is deselected (the UI renders not selected. But when I look at the API, the object of the selected row exists. )

Is this an existing bug in primeNG datatable?